# Xcode saves my old codes whenever i selected core data and i cannot get rid of it in swiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, core-data

So i'm having trouble with trying to open xcode with core data checked.

everytime i do it my old file from years ago suddenly shows up with all the old codes attached and my core data already filled in with that previous attemp. i have tried everything from deleting xcode to deleting my files but i cannot understand where and how xcode saves that old codes and keeps popping it up again and again everytime i clicked that core data check mark. i don't know if its a cache thing because i saw you can delete xcode cache but you have to download some software and i believe apple probably has some built in thing to avoid this. i'm using xcode 13.2.1 please help i've been trying and wrapping my heads around this problem for sometime i can;t seem to find the right answer for it. i have tried to delete xcode profiles like in this article https://cocoacasts.com/how-to-delete-every-record-of-a-core-data-entity

even this https://www.advancedswift.com/batch-delete-everything-core-data-swift/#delete-everything-delete-all-objects-reset-core-data

i still don't understand how to delete them all or where the code should be placed

Thank you so much for your time and have an amazing day/evening

Comment: Welcome to SO - Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve, edit and format your questions. 

Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it is impossible to help you troubleshoot. Your question is poorly worded and doesn’t make a whole lot of sense, if we put bits an pieces together we could come up with a handful of very different solutions.

Comment: I'm sorry about that but i tried to convey it as simply as possible as if everyone is a busy colleague however its hard to describe the experience without going into detail let me give it another try:  When i turn on my xcode and clicking through to make an app with core data my old codes from years ago pops up and i can't seem to get rid of it do you know how to get xcode to open up a fresh new app view without my old codes already appearing before hand?

Comment: Your code appears or the old objects you created? Code being the stuff contained in swift files and objects being the data you created based on the core data entities.

Comment: What I think your issue may be is that your old stores with objects keep appearing, not code. You likely need to “destroy” the store on the devices/simulators, you’ll find the code you need [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70482430/mock-core-data-object-in-swiftui-preview/70482536#70482536) the other possibility is that you used/are using CloudKit. So you need to clear CloudKit Settings>iCloud>Manage Storage>Your App>Delete Data. Both things combined on all the devices will delete everything in CoreData/App folder so be cautions.

Comment: When i tried to delete the iCloud data doesn't have a "Your App" it just had documents and i tried to delete the documents but it deleted both from iCloud and stored files Furthermore i still have no idea how to "Destroy" the store on the devices simulators because my persistence file has no "container = NSPersistentCloudKitContainer(name: "YourAppName")" it only has  let container: NSPersistentContainer i followed this from a tutorial so i don't really understand its implication

Comment: Refer to my first comment. Nobody knows what “codes” means.

Comment: Okay, this thing thing won't go away no matter how many times i delete the files or trying to destroy it it always comes back the same way everytime i clicked the checked button on core data when i'm trying to start a new project:  static var preview: PersistenceController = {
        let result = PersistenceController(inMemory: true)
        let viewContext = result.container.viewContext
        for _ in 0..<10 {
            let newItem = Item(context: viewContext)
            newItem.timestamp = Date()

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242091/discussion-between-arman-and-lorem-ipsum).

Comment: Are you talking about the file that contains that line of code? That line of code is a template file. It appears on everybody’s Xcode when they start a new project with core data . You can delete it afterwards but you can’t start a project with core data without it. The Item entity, the content view file and the persistent controller are template.

Comment: There is a link i have sent to you of a video about the problem i'm facing. the thing is on the tutorial the guy had clean slate nothing else but i had this time.formatter thing is  that common to have this in you contextView  @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext

    @FetchRequest(
        sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Item.timestamp, ascending: true)],
        animation: .default)
    private var items: FetchedResults<Item>

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(items)

Comment: I don’t have Facebook, but that code is template, everybody gets it when they select core data. The only way to get a clean slate is not select core data and then you create the stack, model, etc yourself. If the tutorial is old the stack would be in the App delegate.

Comment: So, its okay then and i can just delete everything should i delete the persistence.swift file as well or not?

Comment: You can delete it but do you need coredata? Do you know how to Create the stack from scratch? Without that code there is no access to core data.

Comment: what does the persistence file actually do if i might ask and to answer your previous questions no i do not

Comment: The persistence file has a `preview` and `shared` Core Data Stack. You can't access CoreData without it or without something similar to it https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/setting_up_a_core_data_stack there are plenty of tutorials out there that will teach you all about it