# Swift Core Data Fatal Eror

Tags: ios, swift

I am learning to work with core data. But why did I get such an error?

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n2HJn.jpg)

[My Core Data Codes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W11ED.jpg)

[My Core Data Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wph6O.jpg)

edit: the problem was due to my renaming "Entity". It's fixed

Comment: Did you read the error reason in the first screenshot (-> *missing mapping model*)? It’s pretty clear.

Comment: I'm just learning but I still don't understand what is missing?

Comment: If it is just a test [`destroy` the store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70482430/mock-core-data-object-in-swiftui-preview/70482536#70482536) you made a change to the model file without creating a new model version. This action is permanent everything will be gone.

Answer (score 1):

You might have changed the Core Data model (names or types of the attributes) after populating it with some data. XCode could not be able to migrate the existing data from the old model to the new one.

You can try re-creating the model from scratch (deleting the whole Entity) if you don’t mind losing the existing data.