# Swift Data Error "The model configuration used to open the store is incompatible with the one that was used to create the store."

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, wwdc, swift-data

While developing an iOS app with Xcode Beta 14 I changed a swift-data model and I started getting this error:

> Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134020 "The model configuration used to open the store is incompatible with the one that was used to create the store." UserInfo={NSAffectedObjectsErrorKey=<NSManagedObject: 0x6000021a9680>

I deleted the app from the device and re built and ran the app. I still got the same error. Now even after rolling back to the previous model version I still get the error, even on different simulators and after deleting the app.

I've tried reverting the model and reinstalling it and I consistently get the error.

This is the schema of the store:

```
Schema
schemaEncodingVersion: 1.0
encodingVersion: 1.0
entities:
 Entity - name: DLDrive, mangledName: 14DriveLoggerKit7DLDriveCm, superEntity: nil)
  subentities:
  storedProperties:
    Attribute - name: id, options: 1, valueType: String, defaultValue: nil, hashModifier: nil
    Attribute - name: startTime, options: 0, valueType: Date, defaultValue: nil, hashModifier: nil
    Attribute - name: endTime, options: 0, valueType: Date, defaultValue: nil, hashModifier: nil
    Attribute - name: startLocationName, options: 0, valueType: String, defaultValue: nil, hashModifier: nil
    Attribute - name: endLocationName, options: 0, valueType: String, defaultValue: nil, hashModifier: nil
    Attribute - name: sunsetTime, options: 0, valueType: Date, defaultValue: nil, hashModifier: nil
    Attribute - name: sunriseTime, options: 0, valueType: Date, defaultValue: nil, hashModifier: nil
    Attribute - name: routeData, options: 0, valueType: Optional<Data>, defaultValue: nil, hashModifier: nil
    Attribute - name: startLocationData, options: 0, valueType: Optional<Data>, defaultValue: nil, hashModifier: nil
    Attribute - name: endLocationData, options: 0, valueType: Optional<Data>, defaultValue: nil, hashModifier: nil
    Attribute - name: weatherStore, options: 0, valueType: Optional<Data>, defaultValue: nil, hashModifier: nil
  inheritedProperties:
  uniquenessConstraints:
    ["id"]
```

In the error it logs this as the model it's trying to save:

```
error saving model context Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134020 "The model configuration used to open the store is incompatible with the one that was used to create the store." UserInfo={NSAffectedObjectsErrorKey=<NSManagedObject: 0x60000217c820> (entity: DLDrive; id: 0x6000002f9040 <x-coredata:///DLDrive/tDBD30926-8298-4666-B224-0A20452E38D42>; data: {
    endLocationData = nil;
    endLocationName = Waterloo;
    endTime = "2023-07-24 22:29:00 +0000";
    id = "74CBAF1C-6068-4155-8D91-0E8FA09FBE36";
    routeData = nil;
    startLocationData = nil;
    startLocationName = Wichita;
    startTime = "2023-07-24 22:10:09 +0000";
    sunriseTime = "0001-01-01 11:27:02 +0000";
    sunsetTime = "0001-01-02 00:45:02 +0000";
    weatherStore = nil;
})}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fully remove macOS Xcode application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73094220/how-to-fully-remove-macos-xcode-application)

Comment: Did you used "iCloud CoreData" (through SwiftData)?

Comment: @Larme I did not use iCloud Coredata, just a local coredata/swiftdata store.

Comment: @Lorem ipsum, I tried to destroy the container using modelContext.container.destroy() however it just crashes the app. Is there specific way you are supposed to destroy the container with swift data?

Comment: Did you do the general Xcode stuff for this, clean the build folder and/or delete the content of the DerivedData folder? Did you try by trashing the db file?

Comment: Yeah, I deleted derived data and cleaned the build cache. Where is the db file located? Thank you! In the mean time I've updated to the latest Xcode beta and the same error still appears.

Comment: Facing the same error, were you able to fix it @Ronan18